# g++ 4.5.1 warns about NULL arguments yet doesn't accept -Wno-nonnull?

Tags: g++

I compile code with `g++ -Wno-nonnull` and get

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wno-nonnull" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
```

but then anyway

```
foo.cxx:455:3: error: null argument where non-null required (argument 2)
```

The compiler is:

```
> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --disable-plugin --with-bugurl=http://bugs.opensuse.org/ --with-pkgversion='SUSE Linux' --disable-libgcj --disable-libmudflap --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-linux-futex --without-system-libunwind --enable-gold --with-plugin-ld=/usr/bin/gold --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --build=x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.1 20101208 [gcc-4_5-branch
revision 167585] (SUSE Linux)
```

For better or worse I do have to support this old compiler.  The code compiles fine on g++ 9.2 with `-Wno-nonnull`.

In `man`, `-Wnonnull` is listed among all the (assumably for all languages) "Warning" and not as a "C and Objective-C-only Warning".

Later in the man page, I see `-Wnonnull (C and Objective-C only)` as the entry for this option specifically.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your problem is in the code, not in the compiler. Passing a null argument where a non-null is required can't work, and you won't find a compiler version that can smooth that over.

Comment: I have a battery of 500+ tests.  The tests are called in a assert-type macro.  The macro has an argument which states the expected value, a string or NULL.  The macro does a strcmp ONLY if the argument isn't NULL.  So, the code as written doesn't do anything that wouldn't work.  G++ is not sufficiently aware to see that the strcmp is only called if the argument is not NULL, so its warning is bogus.  Even in 9.2 it's bogus.  But in 9.2 it can simply be turned off.  How can I turn it off in 4.5?